# How to access method from associated class object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, methods, attributes

I have a following code:

```
import datetime


class Notebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self._id = 0
        self.notes = []

    def new_note(self, memo, tags=""):
        self.notes.append(Note(self, memo, tags))  # creating Note object instance, passing Notebook object

    def get_id(self):
        id = self._id
        self._id += 1
        return id


class Note:

    def __init__(self, notebook, memo="", tags=""):
        self.id = notebook.get_id()  # accesing Notebook object's get_id method to set a new unique id for a Note object
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()
        self.tags = tags
        self.memo = memo

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"[{self.id}, {self.creation_date}, {self.tags}, {self.memo}]"


n = Notebook()
n.new_note("Lorem ipsum", "Latin")
print(n.notes)
```

This is an exercise code I created following a book on OOP. As you can see, I had to (as far as I can tell) pass the Notebook object to a Note object during the creation just to be able to get_id for my new Note object from the Notebook object which created it.

Is there a better way to do it? Is there another way to access the attribute from the creator class without passing the whole object? Is passing an object this way necessary a bad thing at all?

The main question is how to use get_id method of Notebook object from the Note object contained within self.notes attribute of the Notebook object, but without passing the whole Notebook object, as shown in the example.

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just pass the ID?

Comment: Well, this is a learning example. I'm supposed to get it via get_id and would like to know more of the mechanics python uses in this case.

Comment: If you are "supposed to" do something in a certain way according to an exercise that was set for you, then I don't understand how there is an actual question here. What do you perceive to be a problem, exactly; and why do you think it is a problem? We cannot help you read your instructor's (or textbook's) mind.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm not sure if passing objects this way has any downsides. If I do not pass Notebook object, I have no way to access it from Notes, as far as I can see. For instance, if this was inheritance, there is a way in theory - super().get_id(), but still doesn't work because the object n cannot access _id.

Comment: I just have a feeling I'm doing it wrong way somehow, but as far as I can tell, this is a legit way and I can't think of an alternative. That's why I'm here - to put my mind at ease on this. :)

Comment: What if the same note was appended into two different notebooks?

Comment: @wim I don't see a problem. Each would get an id from their respected notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, and for good reason. Imagine that your class accepted that the user specifies the type of note when creating to allow for modification, or runs some user-specified code from the note. I could create a `MyNote` class that replaces the `new_note` method to record all of the new notes the user makes. That would be problematic.

Obviously this is not an issue because you have this hardcoded, but in a more secure and dynamic environment that lets the user specify, a well-disguised malicious class could access the secure class creating it. Such as if your bank decided to use a module that creates loading bars, where it should not be able to look into the class that instantiated it.

Granted, in a truly secure situation, all the code would be under your control anyways.

Comment: so, how would you extract the _id from Notebook without passing the whole collection of notes to the Note class object, but using a get_id, not just passing the ID directly? Instead of id it might be a one time token of some kind that should be accessible only to an object for which was created for. Any ideas?

Comment: Ideally (in an environment where you can't safely give access to classes you call), you would pass the ID as a parameter. Since you are instantiating the note, you can just call `get_id()` inside the parameters rather than pass it: `Note(get_id(), other stuff)`  Granted, in a truly secure situation, all the code would be under your control anyways.

Comment: great workaround! (gotta love pyton). This is much better for the purpose of this example. But what if I can't alter the Notebook class for some reason. Is there a secure way to use get_id() method at all from outside of the Notebook class, from Notes object to obtain an id?

Comment: To call `get_id()` from the Notes object, you would need to pass in the notebook object, or pass in a reference to `get_id`: `Note(get_id, other stuff)` if Note takes `Note(idfunc, other stuff)` and then call `idfunc()` in the Note class. But that also passes information about the Notebook object.

Comment: For instance, Notes object could be required to use get_token() method on Notebook object which contains it to update a token which expires every 60 minutes or so. How would it do it securely?

Comment: In your case, `Note` is hardcoded in, so I would just pass in the Notebook object like you are doing and store it within an instance variable in the Note. Then just call the `get_token()` method off of it.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach could be inheritance.this is assuming th id would auto-increment based on each notebook added to the notebook class. With inheritance you get to do away with some repetition of logic.

```
import datetime


class Note:
    tags = None
    memo = None
    def __init__(self):
       
        self.creation_date = datetime.date.today()   
        self.id = 0
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Note created!'
    
   
    
class Notebook(Note):
    def new_note(self,memo, tags=""):
        self.tags = memo
        self.memo = tags
        return f"[{self.tok()}, {self.creation_date}, {self.tags}, {self.memo}]"
    
    def gen_id(self):
        while True:
            self.id +=1
            yield self.id

    def tok(self):
        a = self.gen_id()
        return next(a)
```

Comment: Interesting, but the goal is that Notebook controls id, not the other way around.